# How can I use bcrypt or scrypt with PHP? Is there a default built in function that uses either of these two?

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt

Is there a default built in function in PHP that allows for use of scrypt or bcrypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP 5.5.0 or above:

Read [the relevant FAQ](http://www.php.net//manual/en/faq.passwords.php) on PHP.net. More notably, you should check out [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) on password hashing. Example:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 12));
```

For earlier versions, look at the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library by ircmaxwell.

Comment: password_hash will handle that bit for you.

Comment: @user51819 With BCRYPT, the salt is stored in the hash. BCRYPT is secure because it is extremely slow and can be made slower if needs be.

Comment: PASSWORD_BCRYPT should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

PHP [Crypt](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.crypt.php) function uses bcrypt.

If you're using PHP 5.5.0 or greater then you can use [Password Hash](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with crypt.

Comment: @user51819 I've added that, but most people still use < PHP v 5.5.0, so I added `crypt` first.

Comment: Since PHP 5.3.7 you can use the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).